# Mail is very slow to open, with fseventsd taking up significant CPU

Tags: mail.app, email, big-sur

My symptoms are very similar to those seen in [Why does Mail.app take three minutes plus to open?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/412916/why-does-mail-app-take-three-minutes-plus-to-open/412944?noredirect=1#comment603036_412944).  Mail takes over 2 minutes to open, and during that time fseventsd is taking up over 90% CPU.  Following the suggestion [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/412944/37113) I collected a spindump:

https://gist.github.com/msridhar/a15fc9fd0feee83c582982eff944192a

Any idea how to fix?  I could try doing an OS update, but I am really curious about the root cause of this one.